# finding common elements in a list c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

can someone please explain how to do this with an example. i have string friends_set for an object, where all data(i.e name,age, friends_set) is sent to a .txt file. how do i find common friends(in friend_set) for two users and output the result.

here's my code so far:

### user.cpp

```
   #include "User.h"
   #include<iostream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include<fstream>

   using namespace std;

   using namespace std;


 int addUser();
 int addUser()
 {
ofstream thefile;  
    thefile.open("users.txt", ios::app);

string firstname;
string lastname;
int age;
string friend_set;

    cout<<"Enter your First Name: ";
    cin>>firstname;
thefile << firstname << ' ';
    cout<<"Enter your Last Name: ";
    cin>>lastname;
thefile << lastname << ",";
    cout<<"Enter your Age: ";
    cin>>age;
    thefile << age<< ",";
    cout<<"Enter name of friends: ";
    cin>>friend_set;
thefile << friend_set << endl;

   thefile.close();
   cout<<"User Added."<<endl;
   return 0;


  while (cin >> firstname >> lastname >> age >> friend_set) {

  thefile << firstname << ' ' << lastname << "," << age << "," << friend_set << endl;

   }
      }
```

i want to write a method called commonfriends() that finds the common friends for any given two users.

Comment: What `return 0;` is doing in middle of your code ? And `Enter name of friends` will take just one friend's name, unless you use `std::getline`. Also you're using `C++`, so use some OO concepts. Re-architecture your code, try grouping users as objects. Also if some ask you to show some code (in previous question which you deleted), don't just blindly write "hello world" code, show some efforts, no one here will do the home work for you. SO is not a private tutorial website !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is to represent the set of friends using a suitable container, probably a `std::vector<std::string>` and make sure that this container is sorted, e.g., using `std::sort()`. If you want to find the overlap of elements in two sorted sequences you can use `std::set_intersection()` which will write the intersection between the two set to an iterator. The result iterator can either reference a target container (using `std::back_inserter()`), write directly to an output stream (using `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>`), or use any other destination an output iterator can write to.